MAUI detect user's inactivity (pointer moved)
I have a .net maui app. I need to detect whenever the user is inactive. If the user is inactive during 1 minute, then auto-logout.
I've seen we have PointerGestureRecognizer which can be used, but that's specific for a single page / element.
Which options do I have in order to detect it in a global / generic way, for the entire app?

There is no direct API in MAUI to detect pointer move globally. What platform do you use?

UWP the main target.

@LiqunShen-MSFT in XF, I could make it with Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Content.PointerMoved += OnPointerMoved, but that way is not working in maui

This related issue might help Gathering keyboard input doesn't work (winui 3).

There is no direct API in MAUI to detect pointer move globally. You may raise a feature request on GitHub.
If you are building Windows apps with .NET MAUI, I think you may refer to this related issue Gathering keyboard input doesn't work (winui 3) . In this thread, @MYPOSConnect posted a method of capturing keyboard, which  applies for capturing mouse movement.
For example, the following code captures the mouse move in the window,
m_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, m_HookProcedure, (IntPtr)0, 0);
For more info, you may refer to Using Hooks.
